# Ionic/Cordova - Get Image path to use on <img src="">

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic app in which I'll take a screenshot of the app.

My problem is that I need to get the image path to use in an image tag src.
But I don't know why isn't happening.

Here's my code:

```
$scope.image = {
    src: ''
};

$scope.takeScreenshot = function() {

    var screenshotLink,
        screenshot = new Image(),
        filename = '';

    navigator.screenshot.save(function(error,res) {
        if(error){
            //console.error(error);
        } else {  
            screenshotLink = res.filePath;
        }
    },'jpg',100,filename);
           
    $scope.image.src = screenshotLink;

};//end_takeScreenshot


<img ng-src="{{ image.src }}" alt="foobar"/>
```

Can you guys help me solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move `$scope.image.src = screenshotLink` into the callback function for `navigator.screenshot.save`. Like so:

```
navigator.screenshot.save(function(error,res) {
    if(error){
        //console.error(error);
    } else {  
        screenshotLink = res.filePath;
        $scope.$apply( function() {
            $scope.image.src = screenshotLink;
        });
    }
},'jpg',100,filename);
```

Comment: That worked but I have to take 2 screenshots to the image appear...
Why is that?

Comment: The view must not be updating when you update the model. I ran into a similar issue today actually, and oddly enough changing `ng-src` to just `src` fixed my problem.

Comment: This article describes the issue you are seeing with the view not updating: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html Basically since the `navigator` callback function happens outside of the context of angular, your view has already digested before `$scope.image.src` is updated. I have updated my answer.